# mongodb Aggregation query limitation sort stage

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Hi extremely helpful comunnity, you cannot believe how many times you save my life before, this time I leave a extrange behaviour in the mongodb engine

Imagine you have a collection like this

```
db.getCollection("thething").insertOne({

"field1" : 99,
"field2" : "lorem ipsum",
"field3" : ISODate("2009-01-09T21:29:20.200Z"),
"field4" : NumberDecimal("38.23"),
"field5" : 99,
"field7" : "lorem ipsum",
"field8" : ISODate("2009-01-09T21:29:20.200Z"),
"field9" : NumberDecimal("38.23"),
"field10" : 99,
"field11" : 1299,
"field12" : "lorem ipsum",
"field13" : ISODate("2009-01-09T21:29:20.200Z"),
"field14" : NumberDecimal("38.23"),
"field15" : 99,
"field16" : "lorem ipsum",
"field17" : ISODate("2009-01-09T21:29:20.200Z"),
"field18" : NumberDecimal("38.23"),
"field19" : 99,
"field20" : "lorem ipsum",
"field21" : 129,
"field22" : "lorem ipsum",
"field23" : ISODate("2009-01-09T21:29:20.200Z"),
"field24" : NumberDecimal("38.23"),
"field25" : 99,
"field26" : "lorem ipsum",
"field27" : ISODate("2009-01-09T21:29:20.200Z"),
"field28" : NumberDecimal("38.23"),
"field29" : 99,
"field30" : 12,
"field31" : "lorem ipsum it dem on ioum",
"field32" : "lorem ipsum",
"field33" : ISODate("2009-01-09T21:29:20.200Z"),
"field34" : NumberDecimal("38.23")

})
```

Then you have a query like this

```
db.getCollection('bigest').aggregate([
{$sort:{
    "field1" : 1,
"field2" : 1,
"field3" : -1,
"field4" :1,
"field5" : -1,
"field7" : 1,
"field8" : 1,
"field9" : 1,
"field10" : 1,
"field11" : 1,
"field12" : 1,
"field13" : 1,
"field14" : 1,
"field15" : 1,
"field16" :1,
"field17" : -1,
"field18" : 1,
"field19" : 1,
"field20" : -1,
"field21" : 1,
"field22" : 1,
"field23" : -1,
"field24" : 1,
"field25" : 1,
"field26" : -1,
"field27" : 1,
"field28" : 1,
"field29" : 1,
"field30" : 1,
"field31" : 1,
"field32" : 1,
"field33" : 1,
"field34" : 1 
}}
```

])

and then the engine throws you this error

```
Error: command failed: {
"operationTime" : Timestamp(1644423981, 1),
"ok" : 0,
"errmsg" : "too many compound keys",
"code" : 13103,
"codeName" : "Location13103",
```

what I don't understand is why that limitation, we can easily reach this limitation in h

Comment: The thing is that we can sort up to 32 fields, if you try adding a new field to the sort stage, that is when you receive the error message

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the [official document of $sort](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/#limits),

> You can sort on a maximum of 32 keys.

I don't think there is a practical use case where you will need to use 32+ $sort keys. One of the common workarounds is that, you can create an auxiliary field for sorting. Another suggestion will be reconsidering your schema design.